# Is there a way to SSH behind two double NAT'd addresses

Tags: nat, ssh-tunnel

Ok, simple to describe problem. No idea on the solution.

I have a LAN at my house, and I have a private IP from the ISP. My friends house has the same situation. Is there a way for me to ssh from my computer to his private server.

My computer (192.168.0.2 from router) | Router (10.16.8.13 from ISP) | Public IP (111.111.111.111) --- Public IP (222.222.222.222) | Router (192.168.125.123 from ISP) | Their Server (192.168.0.143 from their router)

As you can see, both of us are behind a double NAT. I thought about ICMP hole punching. But as this link shows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37472235/flaw-in-icmp-holepunching that apparently rarely works these days.

I considered trying to find a way to have him reverse tunnel to my Android phone, however, even if I researched further to determine how to do that, it appears that my phone also has been given a private IP rather than a public IP.

I know in the desktop world, there are tools (like Team viewer) that allow you to connect one machine to another via their servers. For ssh seems like a good way to get a man in the middle attack...

Comment: It would be a great help if the friend's ISP forwarded a single TCP port to their router and if `222.222.222.222` doesn't change. Ask the ISP. Alternatively the other way around (your ISP forwarding a port to your router, `111.111.111.111` static), which wouldn't be *that* great for reaching your friend's machine, still a starting point for a VPN or SSH-based tunneling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this without help from your ISP or using another common endpoint.

I might spin up a cheap AWS EC2 Instance as an OpenVPN server and then set up OpenVPN from each PC to it (or you could use SSH forwarding).  Of-course, it does not need to be an AWS instance, any minimal VM server would do.

Its also possible you could find a VPN provider that would provide you both with endpoints which could negate the need for an EC2 instance.

Otherwise I guess one of you needs to ask your provider for a static IP address.

Comment: Another option is to look at IPv6 addresses; there are ISP's that give you "private" (NATed) IPv4 addresses and a global routable IPv6 prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to setup TOR hidden service (possibly single onion to provide a bit better performance at the cost of anonymity which I believe is not needed in this case) on the server and TOR client on your workstation. This way you will be able to make connections to your peer's service event behind the double NAT.

Comment: that is an interesting approach. I never thought to try it that way.